# Cloned HTML element not showing

Tags: jquery, html, css

I cloned a div using jQuery and positioned it however I am not sure why it's not showing. Using F12 tools, I can see the element and the top, left, height and width properties are properly set.

```
<div id="divLine" style="width: 12px;height:16px;background-color: #000"></div>

 var clone = $("#divLine").clone().prop('id', 1)[0];
            $(clone).css({
                position: 'absolute',

                left: 20,
                top:20
            })
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9TP5e/)

Comment: You're setting clone as a variable, it's never actually appending anything to the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to append the cloned element to the body or the concerned container.

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/9TP5e/1/

```
$('body').append(clone);
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not append the clone to the parent.

Fixe is here: http://jsfiddle.net/9TP5e/4/

Add this line -

```
$("#divLine").parent().append(clone);
```